# How to remove "Apendix" from the TOC for Apendixes?

Tags: appendices, tocloft

I want to remove the Appendix title from the TOC of a book.
I have this:

[image: Annex with title]

But I want this:

[image: Annex w.o Title]

I figured that using

```
   \begin{appendices}
       \small
       \chapter{Anexo 1}
       \section{Texto 1 do anexo}
       Some text
       \clearpage{\thispagestyle{empty}\cleardoublepage}
   \end{appendices}
```

Gets the "Anexo A" in the TOC entry. However,I figured that using

```
    \begin{appendix}
        \small
        \chapter{Anexo 1}
        \section{Texto 1 do anexo}
        Some text
        \clearpage{\thispagestyle{empty}\cleardoublepage}
    \end{appendix}
```

removes the "Anexo A." just leaving "A."... However, I lose the "Anexos" section entry in TOC (going to add it through `\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Anexos}`.

Need to remove "Anexo" only from the TOC entry with `Appendices`.

I am using package `tocloft` but can find a macro to do this...

Thanks!

Comment: We need more information, like the `\documentclass`. Can you provide a complete minimal example that replicates the behaviour? See [I've just been asked to write a minimal working example (MWE), what is that?](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/5764)

Comment: This is for a book, 650 pages long, but will try to add the MWE.